# Change the checked icon in jQuery Mobile radio button

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I'm working on a cross platform mobile application using jQuery mobile with Backbone.js and Phonegap.

Initially I was using jQuery Mobile version 1.2.1 but when I changed the jQuery Mobile version 1.3.2 found that the radio button's checked icon changed as a 'Tick' mark rather than the usual 'Dot' mark in Android 4.3. The 'Tick' mark was also not visible properly.

Please find the attached image for reference.

I want to change this 'Tick' mark as the usual 'Dot'. Can any one suggest me.

[image]Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? have you also replace jQM 1.2 style sheet with jQM 1.3.2 one?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and I've also updated the style sheet.

Comment: Pls post html markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the copying of sprite images. There is change in icon-file since 1.2.1. The checkbox render because the background-position conflict with the icon file of 1.2.1 which is smaller than 1.3.2.

Reconfirm the image file with the jquery 1.3.2 bundle.

Copy images from 1.3.2 bundle once again in images folder. And Validate.

check github history
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/1d293e0c3ed97e59ac58289071d6ebfee11366c8